# How to execute local script as root in remote servers?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh, remote-server

I need to execute a shell script with root privileges in remote servers. Those servers can't be connected directly via SSH by root user. Thus, I have to connect ssh as normal user first and then change it to root before execute the script. The user and root passwords are parameters stored previously so keyboard interaction is not an option. In that way I'd need a non-(human)-interactive script like:

```
#!/bin/sh

username=admin
password=admin123
hosts={host1..host50}

for hostname in $hosts ;
do
   ssh $username@$hostname sudo 'bash -s' < ./test.sh > results.txt
done
```

How can I do that? In my current code I need to type password for admin user connection and then I have an error like: `sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified`. Maybe a command like `expect` is needed but I don't have much expertise there.

Thanks for your help.

PS: I can't use SSH Keys and administration changes are not allowed in these servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I understand you can `su -` into root but you don't want to edit neither sudoers nor ssh keys.

In this case `expect` is your friend.

[Here](http://www.krazyworks.com/using-expect-with-ssh-and-su/) you can find a quite similar example, but I copy relevant code section here.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 20

set host [lindex $argv 0]
set password [lindex $argv 1]

spawn ssh -tq $host su - root
expect "ssword" { send "pa55w0rd\r" }   # only if you login with password auth
expect "ssword" { send "$password\r" }
expect "#" { send "id -a \r" }          # run script as root
expect "#" { send \"exit\r" }
```

Of course you can embed this in a shell script as below.

```
#!/bin/bash
expect -c "
...
expect eof"
```

I hope I could help!

Comment: This is an awesome solution for my ssh connection issues. However, just one more improvement, I need to execute my local script in remote servers without copy it previously in each server. Is that possible?

Comment: Why do you cannot copy your scipt?? If there is a permission problem then use /tmp. Everybody can write under the /tmp or /var/tmp dirs.

Comment: That's true. In my mind I wanted to save bandwidth and minimize network connections although you're right and it's easier, so I'll add an SCP connection before SSH connection into the `for` loop to copy the script in each server.
Thanks a lot for your invaluable help!

Answer (score 0):

Use SSH Keys to avoid having to enter a password

view this link: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSH_Keys

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer but unfortunately I can't add SSH Keys in those servers. I need to solve this using passwords (unfortunately :( )...

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the sudoers file on the remote host you can tell the sudoer service not to ask password for a specific user to do sudo commands.

`sudo visudo`

add the directive `NOPASSWD` to the user

[Ubuntu site reference](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1132821)

Comment: Thanks a lot but unfortunately administration changes are not allowed on these servers. Is it possible to connect via SSH by user and then by root to execute the script with no human interation? Maybe using `expect` or something similar?

Comment: I see. Well, few years back, I had the same issue but it could be resolved by RSA key authentication (ssh -i RSA_PRIV_KEY_PATH xy@hostname ...) which is not an option as You said... I'm out of ideas, sorry.